# When is an interaction in quadratic regression significant?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, interaction, quadratic-form

I run a regression with a continuous variable $x_2$ and a binary grouping variable $x_1$. We suppose that the effect of $x_2$ is quadratic on the dependent variable $y$ and our question is whether the effect of $x_2$ on $y$ depends on $x_1$.

The formula is $y\sim x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{2}^{2} +  x_{1} : x_{2} +  x_{1} : x_{2}^{2}$. So I get two signifince tests for interaction, i.e. $p$ for $x_{1} : x_{2}$ and $p$ for $x_{1} : x_{2}^{2}$. What of the following statements is true:

- We can say that there is a significant interaction if one of the both interaction coefficiens is significant, no matter whether it is a significant $p$ for $x_{1} : x_{2}$ or a significant $p$ for $x_{1} : x_{2}^{2}$
- We can say that there is a significant interaction if both interactions coefficients are significant
- We must first run a model without any interaction, then a model with both interaction terms, than compare both models using ANOVA. If the $p$ of the F test is significant we can say that there is a significant interaction.

Or is there another approach one must choose in order to test whether the effect of $x_2$ depends on $x_1$ significantly?

---

Edit

To make clearer point three:

model1 <- $y\sim x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{2}^{2}$

model2 <- $y\sim x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{2}^{2} +  x_{1} : x_{2} +  x_{1} : x_{2}^{2}$

ANOVA(model1, model2)

The p value of F in this ANOVA will show whether the effect of x2 depends on x1, i.e. whether the interaction is significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think of indidivual coefficients when a variable is represented by more than one term in the model.  Think of composite (AKA "chunk") tests which test more general hypotheses.  Chunk tests use likelihood ratio, Wald, score, or $F$-tests and have multiple degrees of freedom.  From the model specified above here are some useful chunk tests:

- test all coefficients jointly that relate simultaneously to $x_{1}, x_{2}$ (2 d.f., tests whether effect of $x_2$ depends on $x_1$
- test all coefficients relating to $x_1$ (3 d.f., tests whether $x_1$ is associated with $Y$ for any value of $x_2$)
- test all coefficients relating to $x_2$ (4 d.f., tests whether $x_2$ is associated with $Y$ for any value of $x_1$)

All these chunk tests are provided automatically in the R `rms` package's `anova` function:

```
require(rms)
f <- ols(y ~ x1 * pol(x2, 2))
anova(f)  # provides F stats since using a linear (ordinary least squares) model
```

Chunk tests have interpretability and importantly do not depend on the coding/centering of variables.  They also provide perfect multiplicity adjustment in frequentist modeling.

Comment: Does this correspond to point three in my question? Also see edit of my question.

Comment: Shouldn't "test all coefficients relating to x2" be df 4? x2 has four coefficiens

Comment: Thanks for the correction; fixed.  Yes point 3.

Answer (score 1):

The first one seems right to me.

The second one seems wrong.

The third one answers a somewhat different question: Do the interactions *add* a significant amount to the model?

However, I think it would be better to be more specific in the question and answer, by specifying the two different interactions.

Comment: You can state the 3rd either way, i.e., it tests whether the effect of one variable varies with the level of the other variable.   I wouldn't stress "two different interactions".  $x_2$ is expressed as 2 terms in the model and these terms need to be kept together, otherwise the tests are very coding/origin-dependent.